# Cache replacement policy when consumer behavior is unknown

Tags: caching, prediction, heuristics, uncertainty

Preamble:

I have to populate a very large grid with HTML5 canvases in every cell.
I use `Ext JS` framework, grid cells are complex: variable number of `div` elements with text, one or two simple `svg` elements and a procedurally generated `canvas`. For rendering of table rows `Ext JS` uses `bufferedRenderer`: at every moment of time only a small visible part of table is present at dom tree, during scrolling missing rows are rendered on demand and distant rows are thrown away.

Creating a new canvas every time it needs to be rendered is a perfomance hit, saving every `canvas` element for reattaching them into dom may potentially cause a memory bloat. (For `Ext JS` users: i can't use `Ext.grid.column.Widget` in this particular case).

Problem:

So i decided to implement a cache of my canvases, but i don't know, which [cache replacement policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies) is relevant in my case: i can't predict the way user will scroll my table. Multiple sorting and filtering options make things even more misty. Are there any general considerations for caches where you can't estimate consumer behaviour? Maybe i should simply store every n-th canvas?

Comment: Please add more tags, I would suggest at least "html5" and "javascript"